# Tomcat index.html blank page 404

Tags: tomcat

`http://localhost:8080/` returns the normal tomcat admin page correctly.

My hosts file:

> 127.0.0.1       api

`http://api:8080/index.html` gets a blank page (firebug reports a 404)

I have the app in a seperate location: /html/API/API

I added this to the server.xnl

```
  <Host name="api"  
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        appBase="/html/API/API/web" >
  </Host>
```

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The path of index.html is: /html/API/API/web/index.html

I set this up in Netbeans, if that makes a difference.

I can't seem to get rid of this blank page and properly show the index.html

EDIT:
this worked:

```
  <Host name="api"  
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        appBase="/html/API/API/dist" >
       <Context path="/" docBase="/html/API/API/build/web" reloadable="true">
       </Context>
  </Host>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `appBase` of your Host is where Tomcat looks for all the webapps available to this virtual hosts. It's thus the equivalent of the webapps directory, for your api virtual host. You should thus put war files or exploded war files in this directory, and not your index.html.

If you want a single app for this virtual host, served from the root context, then name it ROOT.war (or ROOT if you deploy an exploded war file):

```
/html/API/API/web/ROOT/index.html
```

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html for details.

Comment: I see: /html/API/API/dist/API/API.war (and exploded there also)
I've pointed appBase="/html/API/API/dist/API" but still get the same problem